# Forms from models

Tags: django

I have different models:

```
Cars
Pictures (models.ForeignKey(Cars))
CarsOptions(models.OneToOneField(Cars))
```

Then I want, that user can add new cars. Forms.py:

```
class NewCarsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cars
        exclude = ('checked','user')
```

In views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_car(request):
    form = NewCarsForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        cmodel = form.save()
        cmodel.save()
        return redirect(profile)
    return render(request, 'add_car.html', { 'form': form,})
```

I have a few questions (yes, I read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)).

1. As you can see, user can add only "car", not pictures and options. How to do this on one page in one form?
2. `exclude = ('checked','user')`, it means, that I want to make all new positions with checked=0, so I can filter them. And the user-field - users cant choose user in a list. How to take user id (who adds car) in `form.save()`?

Thanks.

Update:

```
class Pictures(models.Model):
    cars = models.ForeignKey(Cars, related_name='pictures')
    width = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=640)
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=480)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=lambda inst, fname: 'users_img/' + 'cars' + fname, height_field='height', width_field='width', max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: 1. This is 3 different model forms. If the 3 have permanent one-to-one relations to each other why not to combine them in 1 model?

Comment: not 3, one model with 1 2 1

Comment: It's not clear do you mean a single Django form you want or do you mean a single html form?

Comment: Use inline formset and getting the user is easy. If no one answer this, I will answer it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**forms.py**

```
class NewCarsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cars
        exclude = ('checked','user')

PicturesFormset = inlineformset_factory(Cars, Pictures, 
    fields=('field_name', 'field_name'), can_delete=True)

CarsOptionsFormset = inlineformset_factory(Cars, CarsOptions, 
    fields=('field_name', 'field_name'), can_delete=True)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def add_car(request):
    cars = Cars(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewCarsForm(request.POST, instance=cars)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            cmodel = form.save()

            picture_formset = PicturesFormset(request.POST, request.FILES,
                instance=cmodel)
            if picture_formset.is_valid():
                picture_formset.save()

            option_formset = CarsOptionsFormset(request.POST, instance=cmodel)
            if option_formset.is_valid():
                option_formset.save()

            return redirect(profile)

    form = NewCarsForm()
    picture_formset = PicturesFormset(instance=Cars())
    option_formset = CarsOptionsFormset(instance=Cars())

    return render(request, 'add_car.html', { 
        'form': form,
        'picture_formset': picture_formset,
        'option_formset': option_formset,
    })
```

**template**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <h4>Car:</h4>
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <h4>Picture:</h4>
    {{ picture_formset.as_p }}

    <h4>Options:</h4>
    {{ option_formset.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user_id'")`

Comment: remove option_formset...Try to save Cars and Picture only, we will see if that error will shown again. Test it one by one so that you will know the root of the problem. In that way, it is easy to debug and fix the problem

Comment: I remove 1 by one, so I have only Cars, but the error is the same.

Comment: so the error is from here `cars = Cars(user=request.user)`. Is your Cars model field for user is OnetoOneField()?

Comment: yes, it is, `user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')`

Comment: From the error, it looks like the system didn't want to save the new data which has the same user id from the existing data in your database

Comment: Change it to ForeignKey to allow the user enter other data. OneToOneField only allow to save one data per user.

Comment: Its very strange, but it doesnt add pictures, they arent adds in folder. In admin interface it works fine. I have update my post with picture model.

Comment: Because you forgot to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the template form

Comment: Please sometimes teach yourself to handle and fix simple errors